# SELECT statement FROM sp_execute_remote

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Hi can someone help me how could I achieve this.

```
  DECLARE @ACTUAL_YEAR INT = 2016
    select DATE_YEAR
    from
            (EXEC sp_execute_remote
            N'MYDATABASE',
            N'SELECT * FROM dbo.MY_TABLE_FUNCTION(@DATE_YEAR)',
            N'@DATE_YEAR INT',
            @ACTUAL_YEAR)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @bermz kastral, was your question addressed?. If so, can you please mark it as answered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same approach as in SQL Server:

- Firstly, the result set of stored procedure to be saved in a temporary table
- Then manipulation of the resultset by querying that recently created object

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE #resultset 
(
 Col1.. ColN..
)

DECLARE @ACTUAL_YEAR INT = 2016

INSERT #resultset 
EXEC sp_execute_remote
            N'MYDATABASE',
            N'SELECT * FROM dbo.MY_TABLE_FUNCTION(@DATE_YEAR)',
            N'@DATE_YEAR INT',
            @ACTUAL_YEAR

SELECT DATE_YEAR FROM #resultset
```

Comment: If you are using Azure DB you need to add the column name [$ShardName] nvarchar(500) to your #resultset temp table or you will get an error that the columns don't match.  Azure adds this column to the results set.  Hope this helps someone!